# How to count word dictionary in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I have a question about dictionary handling in Python.

I wonder how to compare the dictionary with the list of words.

[example of my input]

```
text = ['fall', 'big', 'pocket', 'layer', 'park', ...]
mylist = ['spring', 'summer', 'fall', 'winter', 'school', ...]
```

[make dictionary code]

```
lst_dic = {mylist : 0 for mylist in mylist }
lst_dic
```

I want to know how many words matching in `mylist` from `text`.

[fail code]

```
lst_dic = {}
for w in mylist:
    if w in text_1_1:
        lst_dic[w] += 1
    else:
        lst_dic[w] = 0
```

As a result, I want to know dictionary key and value.
Like this:

```
{ 'spring':0,
  'summer':3,
  'fall':1,
  'winter':0,
  ...
}
```

Then, I want to extract more than 10 count value of attributes.

Please take a look at this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't initializing the `lst_dic` correctly in the case of the first time a key (word) occurs in the `mylist`. Hence, you get a `KeyError`.

Use `collections.defaultdict` to initialize the dictionary instead. This allows you to remove the `else` branch from your code, and merely increment each time you encounter the frequency a word in `text`.

```
import collections

text = ['fall', 'big', 'pocket', 'layer', 'park']
mylist = ['spring', 'summer', 'fall', 'winter', 'school']

lst_dic = collections.defaultdict(int)
for w in mylist:
    if w in text:
        lst_dic[w] += 1

# Show the counts of all `text` words occurring in `mylist`:
print(dict(lst_dic))

# Extract those with counts > 10:
print([e for e in lst_dic if lst_dic[e] > 10])

# Or, if you want it as a dictionary:
print({e: lst_dic[e] for e in lst_dic if lst_dic[e] > 10})
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume a `defaultdict` as `lst_dic`. Now, Compare the dictionary `key` to text. if matches then `count+1`. Now extract the final dictionary if the value is greater than 10.

```
from collections import defaultdict
text = ['fall', 'big', 'pocket', 'layer', 'park']
mylist = ['spring', 'summer', 'fall', 'winter', 'school']
lst_dic = defaultdict(int)

for w in mylist:
    if w in text:
        lst_dic[w] += 1
result = {key: value for key, value in lst_dic.items() if value > 10}
print(result)
```

Comment: `for w in lst_dic.keys():` -- should be looping through `mylist` I think

Comment: @costaparas may be so but he also added a snippet of making a dictionary  using `mylist`

Comment: I do see that in the question, I think that was at attempt at initializing `lst_dic`. But the thing is, if you only loop through `lst_dic`, then the counts would be at most 1 - since they are after all keys of a dict. You could verify by simple example, e.g. put `mylist *= 100` and you should be seeing `fall` output with the given sample data.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using many loops, I prefer to follow this approach:

1- you count all words in **text** using Counter().

```
from collections import Counter
text_count = dict(Counter(text))
```

2- Create an empty dictionary, mylist_count, iterate through mylist, match it with text_count key and set mylist_count values.

```
mylist_count = dict()
for el in mylist:
    try:
        mylist_count[el] = text_count[el]
    except:
        mylist_count[el]=0
```